# Is there an audio mistake in the Carole King You've Got A Friend YouTube video?

Tags: recording, noise

I think I've discovered an anomaly in this video at approximately 4:13.

It is subtle and I describe it as a faint ringtone on a phone. A friend described this as a sonic disruption and another described it as a rinky-tink piano.

To my ears it has no rhythmic, melodic or harmonic value and might be an artifact or anomaly resulting in uploading it to YouTube. I can't imagine this being intentional.

But I wonder if this is present in the original vinyl album.
Any insight here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

It's James Taylor - I've isolated it a bit in Izotope you you can better hear it's an acoustic guitar lick.
[Izotope doesn't have a piano filter, so basically I've removed vocals, bass & percussion which leaves mainly mic spill from those, then isolated the left channel to mono. It ain't perfect;)

BTW, it wouldn't surprise me if the track was recorded with everyone in the same room, all at once, maybe a couple of baffles between people for a tiny bit of separation - hence the huge amount of spill & a bit of a vague mix.

https://soundcloud.com/graham-lee-15/mono-guit-james-taylor

He's listed as being [on the track](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You%27ve_Got_a_Friend) [as well as making his [own version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mud_Slide_Slim_and_the_Blue_Horizon) almost simultaneously, also with Carole King.]

Incidentally, the Soundcloud embed is *still* broken - Meta [Soundcloud embedding - new issues?](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3643/soundcloud-embedding-new-issues)

Comment: I tried to listen to Mono-Guit on SoundCloud but all I hear is a faint background hum; basically silence.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the file. Sounds like you've got a sum-to-mono with phase inversion issue somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

This was answered before I got a chance but I’ll throw my two cents in. Yes, it is a guitar. It sounds to me like an acoustic nylon string played with a pick. The part is there throughout panned pretty hard left and is mostly playing light fills and chords throughout. It is also very low in the mix and unfortunately the only thing that really cuts through are the high frequencies and string noise. At that point he plays an Ab major pentatonic riff right after the lyric: “call”. Below is basically what he plays, octave transposed for guitar. The chords are for reference and are not played by him.

[image]

Comment: Check the rhythm on the first half of this bar?  I hear the phrase starting with 1 +a 2e+a, slight grace note before 1

Comment: @Edward I hear something very soft and fairly indistinguishable on the 1 and the last 16th of the previous bar but only on the isolated track provided by Tetsujin. I can’t even be sure it’s the guitar. It is inaudible in the actual recording, which is what I used to do my basic transcription.

Comment: I can hear quite clearly that it is the guitar track (it helps that the guitar track is hard panned left.), but I can't clearly make out what notes.  I think both may be (low) F.

Comment: @Edward whatever it is, (it sounds like low notes to me also, maybe a low C up to an F) I reiterate that it is only barely audible to me on the isolated track. It also doesn’t seem musically connected to the riff I transcribed.

Answer (score 2):

It's [James Taylor on acoustic guitar](https://www.discogs.com/release/387851-Carole-King-Tapestry). You can can hear him playing very quietly through a lot of the song, but at 4:13 he gets a bit carried away.

Comment: Does that really sound like an acoustic guitar to you? He is an accomplished guitarist.

Comment: It sounds more like a ukelele.

Comment: Yep, this does have a uke-like tone. But I can't see the mixing and mastering people wanting that in the mix. What purpose does it serve, I find it annoying.

Comment: To be fair, James was battling a bit of a heroin addiction during the recording of this song. I can only imagine it crept into his playing just a bit.

Comment: @Steve You'll either have to live with it or get hold of the original master tapes and remix it yourself.